# Better SQL to pull threads & messages?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am super rusty on my SQL and I want to make sure I am not writing something that will fail under any type of load.

I have a single Messages table that looks like this:

```
ID int [PK]
ThreadId nvarchar(32)
Read bit
Archived bit
Timestamp datetime
/*---Other non-relevant columns---*/
Sender_MemberId int [FK]
Receiver_MemberId int [FK]
```

Similar to Gmail, I want to be able to pull all of the threads and all the messages of that thread based on normal messaging uses (inbox, sent, archived, etc...).

Here's the SQL I'm currently using for the inbox:

```
SELECT * FROM [Messages]
WHERE [ThreadId] IN 
(
    SELECT [ThreadId]
    FROM [Messages]
    WHERE ([Receiver_MemberId] = @MemberId)
)
ORDER BY [ThreadId] DESC, [Timestamp] DESC
```

This works as I want, but is there a better way to do this?  Or if not, what should indexes should I have?

**UPDATE:** Per Aaron's good suggestion, I've added paging and reduced the amount of info I am pulling right off the bat.

New SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.[ThreadId], m.[Subject], m.[To], m.[From], m.[Timestamp]
FROM 
(   
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MessageId) AS RowNumber , ThreadId
    FROM [Messages]
    WHERE [Sender_MemberId] = @p1
) 
AS t
INNER JOIN [Messages] m ON m.ThreadId = t.ThreadId
WHERE t.RowNumber BETWEEN @Skip + 1 AND @Skip + @Take
ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
```

Comment: Do you really need to pull all the threads and all the messages in one go? I would say in general you need to pull all the thread titles (and maybe the counts of the messages) but not "drill in" until they select a thread, then you go get all the messages for that thread. If you are getting all the threads and all the messages, then another tactic you can take from Google's approach is paging (e.g. 50 threads at a time vs. ALL threads).

Comment: Aaron, good points all.  I had planned on adding paging later, but now realize I need to add it from the get-go.  In terms of getting all the messages in one go, I was going to throw them in the cache, but that might not be the best way to go.  I'll think about that some more.

Comment: If your site is active, how long do you expect your cache to be valid? If the site is popular, how big do you expect your cache to be?

Answer (score 1):

You  don't need a sub query, this should do

```
  SELECT Id
       , [ThreadId]
       , read
       , archived
       , timestamp
  FROM   [Messages]
  WHERE  [Receiver_MemberId] = @MemberId
  ORDER BY [ThreadId] DESC, [Timestamp] DESC
```

it's good practice to name the columns you require, rather than use *

Comment: *Do you need to order by threadid?* Probably. Most sites show a list of threads and then you expand and see all the messages under that thread. If you order by timestamp you can have a message from thread 1, then a message from thread 12, then a message from thread 24, then another message from thread 1...